# How to Display SQL Column Data in an Input Value

Tags: php, sql

So far I have the code

```
if (isset($_GET["job_pos_sort"])) {
     $sn = (int)($_GET["job_pos_sort"]);
```

`$job_posname = "SELECT job_pos FROM careers WHERE job_pos_sort = $sn";`

and

```
<td><input name="job_pos_sort" type="text" id="job_pos_sort" value="<?php echo $sn;?>"></td>

<td><input name="job_pos" type="text" id="job_pos" value="<?php echo $job_posname;?>"></td>
```

and the code displays the job_pos_sort input value correctly. I am trying to make the job_pos value display correctly in the second input. The second input value appears blank on my web page.

My web page URL looks like this : mywebpage.ca/phptester/updatecareers.php?job_pos_sort=4

Here is my whole code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'ddsehdscom';
$dbuser = 'kedsagbm';
$dbpass = 'Kisazer';
$dbname = 'kedsgbm';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_GET["job_pos_sort"])) {
    $sn = (int)($_GET["job_pos_sort"]);
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$job_pos_sort = $_POST['job_pos_sort'];
$job_pos = $_POST['job_pos'];

$sql = "UPDATE careers ".
       "SET job_pos = '$job_pos' ".
       "WHERE job_pos_sort = $job_pos_sort" ;

$retval = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
echo "Click <a href='displaydb.php'>here</a> to return to the table";

}
else
{
$job_posname = "SELECT job_pos FROM careers WHERE job_pos_sort = $sn";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $job_posname);
$array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$job_posname=stripslashes($array['job_pos']);
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee ID</td>
<td><input name="job_pos_sort" type="text" id="job_pos_sort" value="<?php echo $sn;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee Salary</td>
<td><input name="job_pos" type="text" id="job_pos" value="<?php echo $job_posname;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
}
else {
        echo ("No employee id given.");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you, for any help.

Kelsey

Comment: can you be a bit clearer, you're setting the value of both inputs the same. in one input the value is showing in the second it is not? your query should be fixed, it is wide open for sql injection. you should sanitize $sn=$_GET['job_pos_sort'];

Comment: Sorry, the value for the second input was meant to be <?php echo $job_posname;?>. Well, it is for a small company so I don't think they will be doing anything to detrimental by updating the table.

Comment: Are you sure `$job_posname` returns you something?

Comment: The $job_posname is not showing anything in my second input value.

Comment: as @Grish mentioned on my answer, and I updated my answer, $sn isn't being changed into its value, it is being treated as a string because inside a single quote. replace $job_posname = 'SELECT job_pos FROM careers WHERE job_pos_sort = $sn'; by $job_posname = "SELECT job_pos FROM careers WHERE job_pos_sort = $sn";

Comment: In your query $sn will treated as a part of string cos of single quote. Change it to double quote which might give you the desired output

Comment: I changed that and it is still not working. I updated the code in my question to what you guys told me to input.

Comment: hehe, sorry just noticed, you're connecting to mysql. 1 min I'll update my answer to tell you what to replace in your code.

Comment: Do you get any output for $array['job_pos']? can you please echo and see if you get any value? use print_r() in case of array.

Comment: I updated my answer, you really shouldn't be learning to use mysql_*, you'll be learning for nothing as it will be removed in the next major release of PHP. Start using mysqli or PDO

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming Mysqli_ is just mysql code with the letter i at the end of Mysql.

Comment: Oh boy.. You are executing query in `if(isset($_POST['update']))` block and using the value in of that query in else statement.So if you don't have $POST['update'] value query will never execute and so no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'dscom';
$dbuser = 'kesgbm';
$dbpass = 'Ksr';
$dbname = 'kam';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_GET["job_pos_sort"])) {
    $sn = (int)($_GET["job_pos_sort"]);
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$job_pos_sort = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['job_pos_sort']);
$job_pos = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['job_pos']);

$sql = "UPDATE careers ".
       "SET job_pos = '$job_pos' ".
       "WHERE job_pos_sort = $job_pos_sort" ;

$retval = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
echo "Click <a href='displaydb.php'>here</a> to return to the table";

}
else
{
    $job_posname = "SELECT job_pos FROM careers WHERE job_pos_sort = $sn";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $job_posname);
    $array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $job_posname=stripslashes($array['job_pos']);
    ?>
<form method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee ID</td>
<td><input name="job_pos_sort" type="text" id="job_pos_sort" value="<?php echo $sn;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee Salary</td>
<td><input name="job_pos" type="text" id="job_pos" value="<?php echo $job_posname;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
}
else {
        echo ("No employee id given.");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even catch that he wasn't actually executing the SQL statement.

Comment: This won't work.  Single quotes won't allow PHP to process $sn in the query.

Comment: @CodeBird please correct me if I am wrong but if he wasn't executing the query than wouldn't he be getting the query as output in the textbox.. Also $sn in query won't be executing to the value as in single quote?

Comment: @Grish good catch for the $sn didn't pay attention to the single quote, as for the query inside the input I think he had a typo in his that's why it was blank.

Comment: yeah I commented, please update your code, I had a typo in my code

Comment: $query=mysqli_query($job_posname); should be $query=mysqli_query($conn, $job_posname); and $retval=mysqli_query($conn, $sql); not the inverse. Look at mysqli syntax

Comment: @CodeBird see my comment on the question. maybe he is missing something important here. It may not be the mysql issue at all

Comment: It maybe that too, but we have we can't know as long as there are code errors

Comment: but he is executing the query in if block and using the result in the else block...:O

Comment: Lol right! I am on an iPad now. Can't really help anymore lol

Comment: updated all the answer to fix all the issues. Hope this will help you learn

Comment: Thanks CodeBird, you've been very consistent with your assistance. It is still not working, though. I have updated the code to what you suggested.

Comment: @Michael I can't see anything wrong with the code. Are you sure $sn exists in the database? Like you're selecting where job_pos_sort=1 are you sure 1 exists?

Comment: Me too! Yes, in the first input it displays the value of $sn correctly.

Comment: No I meant does it exist in the DB for this query to return something: SELECT job_pos FROM careers WHERE job_pos_sort = $sn

Comment: Well it must if it is showing job_pos_sort=1 in the first input, right? 1 does exist in the database for job_pos_sort. I'm basically clicking an edit link on a php table. The code for the link is "<a href='updatecareers.php?job_pos_sort={$r['job_pos_sort']}'>Edit</a>". The link gives $sn it's value of whatever job_pos_sort is, allowing me to edit that specific row. I don't know why the query wouldn't return anything, though.

Comment: It works! Randomly put in "<?php echo "$job_posname";?>" above the second input and it displayed both properly. Thanks for the help @CodeBird.

Comment: Took out the echo I just put in above the second input, and it still works! Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if '$job_posname' has a value in it after your query runs.  I think that you'll need quotes around your '$sn' value in your query in order to get a result.

```
$job_posname = 'SELECT job_pos FROM careers WHERE job_pos_sort = "$sn"';
```

Answer (score 0):

first connect with database:

```
<?php    
   $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $query= "SELECT job_pos FROM careers WHERE job_pos_sort = $sn";
    $job_posname_res = mysql_query($query,$link);
    $job_posname_object =mysql_fetch_object($job_posname_res);
    $job_posname = $job_posname_object->job_pos;
    mysql_close($link);
    ?> 
    <td><input name="job_pos_sort" type="text" id="job_pos_sort" value="<?php echo $sn;?>"></td>

    <td><input name="job_pos" type="text" id="job_pos" value="<?php echo $job_posname;?>"></td>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be advising people to use mysql_* as it is deprecated!

Comment: @CodeBird agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your server may not allow short tags in php. You have to turn this on. 
However it may also be  the fact that job_pos_name is not defined in your short tag php.
Your answer then would be to define job_pos_name in the short tags.
If the problem is not allowing short tags then echo our inputs with php and put a php variable in value with ".$variable."